# Tuning a Postgres INSERT only database

Tags: postgresql, performance, insert

I am designing a database which will have many inserts and selects, but no updates.

Are  there any considerations to take (in order to have high query performance) while knowing no tuple updates will occur?

There is one simple table, of `int (id),timestamp,real`, there will be about 100 inserts per second.

**Edit:** `timestamp` is not the insertion time, the int is a random short number.
Most of the queries are selection of data between two dates (1 minute - 1 week), for a group of id (up to 10).

Comment: crucial information missing: what kind of queries will you be doing (eg "give me all rows for a particular `int` or for a particular `timestamp` range). Should we assume the `timestamp` is the insert time and the `int` is randomly distributed?

Comment: Thanks, added more details, I assume no read locks are needed as the historical data never get updated, I wonder if there is a way to tell Postgres the table data is not updated.

Comment: How often will this thing being queried?  Should the queries be really real-time, or is a (possibly very small) delay acceptable?

Comment: A delay of 1 minutes is acceptable, this thing is queries for small data sets (last 10 minutes of data per id) every few minutes.
Once per few hours, a larger queries might happen, but the performance is less important.
I am having a covering index which decreased the query time significantly.

Comment: what's you covering index? How many rows are you expecting per `id`?

Comment: b-tree - ("timestamp" NULLS FIRST, id NULLS FIRST, value NULLS FIRST);

Comment: The number of rows per id will be changed as the database grows.

Comment: If you are querying "for a group of id (up to 10)", you might want to consider having `id` first in your covering index. You'll need to construct your query in such a way that ensures it does one range-scan per ID in your list (eg with `union all`). Incidentally, 'read locks' [aren't relevant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html).

Comment: Thanks jack, I mistakenly wrote timesamp first, the id is first in the covering index as you suggest, thanks!  I will see if the `union all` helps.

Comment: would be good to see an EXPLAIN PLAN before and after

Comment: Can you insert many rows at once ? Do you have triggers or foreign keys on this table ? 100 inserts per second isn't that high, you shouldn't have performance issues.